# Date and category link underneath thumbnail ( Better Method )

Tags: html, css

I need to position the date and category link underneath the image. I have tried the following CSS but i don't think its a great solution. is there a better way to do this?

```css
.alignleft {
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
}

a.alignleft, img.alignleft {
    margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

.entry-content {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<article class="post-214 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-category-one tag-tag-one entry" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork"><header class="entry-header"><h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline"><a class="entry-title-link" rel="bookmark" href="http://demo.local/single-post/">Post In Category 1</a></h2>
</header><div class="entry-content" itemprop="text"><div class="image-container"><a href="http://demo.local/single-post/" title="Post In Category 1"><img src="https://i.ibb.co/3rTk8s7/demo-150x150.png" class="alignleft post-image entry-image" alt=""></a><div class="custom-meta"><p class="entry-meta"><time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2019-01-29T08:05:39+00:00">January 29, 2019</time></p><p class="entry-meta"><span class="entry-categories"><a href="http://demo.local/category/category-one/" rel="category tag">Category One</a></span></p></div></div><p>This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with them what is on your mind.This is an example of a WordPress post, you could edit […]</p>
</div><footer class="entry-footer"></footer></article>
```

Comment: Did you try flexbox? `.entry-content {display: flex}`

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is all you need:

```
.entry-content {display: flex}
```

You can style more after but its what you are looking for. For more flex info, check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex

Answer (score 0):

This should work, for these kind of things it is really handy to use flexbox, you can train on it with this. https://flexboxfroggy.com

```css
.entry-content{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.info{
  padding-left:1rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="post-214 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail category-category-one tag-tag-one entry" itemscope="" itemtype="https://schema.org/CreativeWork">

<header class="entry-header">
   <h2 class="entry-title" itemprop="headline">
   <a class="entry-title-link" rel="bookmark"            href="http://demo.local/single-post/">Post In Category 1</a>
   </h2>
</header>

<article class="entry-content" itemprop="text">

 <div class="image-container">
  <a href="http://demo.local/single-post/" title="Post In Category 1">
  <img src="https://i.ibb.co/3rTk8s7/demo-150x150.png" class="alignleft post-image entry-image" alt="">
  </a><div class="custom-meta">
  <p class="entry-meta">
  <time class="entry-time" itemprop="datePublished" datetime="2019-01-29T08:05:39+00:00">January 29, 2019</time></p>
  <p class="entry-meta"><span class="entry-categories"><a href="http://demo.local/category/category-one/" rel="category tag">Category One</a></span></p></div></div>
  
  <p class="info">This is an example of a post, you could edit this to put information about yourself so readers know where you are coming from. You can create as many posts as you like in order to share with them what is on your mind.This is an example of a WordPress post, you could edit […]</p>
<article><footer class="entry-footer"></footer></section>
```